# Save changes to a mailitem's inspector

Tags: powershell, com, outlook, powershell-2.0

I am writing a script in PowerShell 2.0 to create a bunch of appointments on a calendar using an outlook COM object.  I had the code fully working, but the end user requested adding formatted tables to the body of the appointments.  After trying several other options I ended up using the `Mailitem.GetInspector.WordEditor` to edit the body.  However I am unable to get the body to be saved without having to open the item in Outlook and hitting save.  Here is the relevant code:

```
$newCalenderItem = $folder.Items.Add()
$newCalenderItem.Subject = $appt.Subject
$newCalenderItem.Location = $location
$newCalenderItem.Start = $d.AddHours($timeSlot.Time)
$newCalenderItem.Duration = 60 * $timeSlot.Duration
$newCalenderItem.BusyStatus = 2
$newCalenderItem.ReminderSet = $false
$newCalenderItem.Categories = $appt.Category
$newCalenderItem.Body = ""
if ($appt.BodyFile) {
    $newCalenderItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Range().InsertFile("C:\Body.rtf", "", $false, $false, $false)

    #this doesn't save it
    $newCalenderItem.GetInspector.WordEditor.Close([ref] -1)
}
#this saves everything but the body
$newCalenderItem.Save()
```

I have tried `GetInspector.Close()`, `WordEditor.Close()`, and `WordEditor.Save()` which brings up a save as dialog.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the AppointmentItem.RtfBody property - Outlook appointments, tasks, and contacts work with RTF rather than HTML. You can read your RTF file into a variant array of byte to pass to the RtfBody property.

Comment: I am editing a MailItem, not an appointment.  I have tried editing RTFBody but always get the error `Exception setting "RTFBody": "Value does not fall within the expected range."` so I turned to using the `MailItem`'s inspector.

Comment: Please show your code. Did you create a variant array of byte to hold the data?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself digging around the inspector's members and wanted to post the answer if anyone finds this searching for their own problem.
You need to save the inspector's `CurrentItem` not the inspector itself.

```
$newCalenderItem.GetInspector.CurrentItem.Save()
```